# Task IndexError('string index out of range',) in celery

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I have created an asynchronous email sending to the job poster when job seeker applies for the job using celery and rabbitmq. I have used smtp(gmail) for email service.However I am getting an error which I could not figure out where exactly is the error coming from and how do i resolve it. The error is something like this

```
Task job.tasks.send_resume_to_job_poster[a1d2f76e-5e38-4560-8576-0c43accff696] raised unexpected: IndexError('string index out of range',)
```

Here is my code

In a nutshell what I am doing is, I am generating the pdf from the html template and sending an email to the job poster but for testing I am using seeker email

```
def html_to_pdf_view(resume):
    print('resume', resume)
    html_string = render_to_string('resume/resume.html', {'resume': resume})

    html = HTML(string=html_string)
    html.write_pdf(target='/tmp/resume_{}.pdf'.format(resume.id))

    fs = FileSystemStorage('/tmp')
    with fs.open('/tmp/resume_{}.pdf'.format(resume.id)) as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response[
            'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="resume_{}.pdf"'.format(resume.id)
        return response

    return response


@shared_task
def send_resume_to_job_poster(poster, seeker):
    resume = User.objects.get(email=seeker).resume
    generated_pdf = html_to_pdf_view(resume)
    subject = "{} has applied for the job".format(resume.name)
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_email = [seeker]
    message = "if you don't want to recieve such message please we can't do anything for you."
    email = EmailMessage(
        subject,
        message,
        from_email,
        [to_email]
    )
    email.attach_file('/tmp/resume_{}.pdf'.format(resume.id))
    print('email', email)
    # email.attach("resume_{}.pdf".format(resume.id),
    #              generated_pdf, 'application/pdf')
    return email.send()
```

Error log in detail

```
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,301: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] html
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,302: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] <html>
  <head>
    <title>Tushant Khatiwada</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Tushant Khatiwada</h1>
    <h3>Django Developer</h3>
  </body>
</html>
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,302: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] ################################################
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,303: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] httpResponse
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,303: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] <HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/pdf">
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,303: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] ################################################
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,303: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Step 1 - Fetching and parsing HTML - HTML string
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,329: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Step 2 - Fetching and parsing CSS - CSS string
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,367: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Step 3 - Applying CSS
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,381: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Step 4 - Creating formatting structure
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,383: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Step 5 - Creating layout - Page 1
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,464: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Step 6 - Drawing
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,468: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Step 7 - Adding PDF metadata
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,472: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] response
[2017-09-27 11:48:23,472: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] <HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/pdf">
[2017-09-27 11:48:25,199: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task job.tasks.send_resume_to_job_poster[a1d2f76e-5e38-4560-8576-0c43accff696] raised unexpected: IndexError('string index out of range',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tushant/.virtualenvs/startup/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tushant/.virtualenvs/startup/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tushant/Projects/startup/job/tasks.py", line 60, in send_resume_to_job_poster
    return email.send()
  File "/home/tushant/.virtualenvs/startup/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 348, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/tushant/.virtualenvs/startup/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 111, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/home/tushant/.virtualenvs/startup/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in _send
    recipients = [sanitize_address(addr, encoding) for addr in email_message.recipients()]
  File "/home/tushant/.virtualenvs/startup/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
    recipients = [sanitize_address(addr, encoding) for addr in email_message.recipients()]
  File "/home/tushant/.virtualenvs/startup/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 161, in sanitize_address
    address = Address(nm, addr_spec=addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/headerregistry.py", line 42, in __init__
    a_s, rest = parser.get_addr_spec(addr_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1988, in get_addr_spec
    token, value = get_local_part(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1800, in get_local_part
    if value[0] in CFWS_LEADER:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: can you paste the traceback as text? I'm not colorblind but I'm thinking I am when reading your image.

Comment: Haha ok Sure I will

Comment: I have updated error log in detail. I have included the response as well to show it is working upto  pdf generation.

Comment: much better now. the exception shows that `value` is empty...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry, which value?

Comment: it's in the libraries. Probably because you're calling some API with an empty string? dunno.

Comment: I updated my code